# Query SQL with similar values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to make a query to a base using as a comparison a string like this `12345678`, but the value to compare is this way`12.345.678`, if I do the following query it does not return anything.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE CAMPO = '12345678'
```

Where CAMPO would have the value of (12.345.678), if I replace `=` with a `like`, it does not return the data either

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE CAMPO like '12345678%'
SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE CAMPO like '%12345678'
SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE CAMPO like '%12345678%'
```

None of the 3 previous consultations works for me, how can I make this query?

The value can be of either 7, 8 or 9 numbers and the. It has to be every 3 from the end to the beginning

Comment: `WHERE REPLACE(CAPMO, '.', '') = '12345678'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`REPLACE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function to replace all the dots `'.'` as

```
SELECT *
FROM(
     VALUES ('12.345.678'),
            ('23.456.789')
    ) T(CAMPO)
WHERE REPLACE(CAMPO, '.', '') = '12345678';
```

Your query should be

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE REPLACE(CAMPO, '.', '') = '12345678';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can compare the string without the dots to a `REPLACE(StringWithDots, '.','')`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to convert the number to numeric

So you can use < and > operators and all functions that require you to have a number...

the best way to achieve this is to make sure you remove any unecessary dots and convert the commas to dots. like this

```
CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 2), 
               REPLACE(
                       REPLACE('7.000,45', '.', ''),
                       ',', '.'
                      )
              )
```

I hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

A [SARGABLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) solution would be to write a function that takes your target value (`'12345678'`) and inserts the separators (`'.'`) every third character from right to left. The result (`'12.345.678'`) can then be used in a `where` clause and benefit from an index on `CAMPO`.

The following code demonstrates an approach without creating a user-defined function (UDF). Instead, a recursive common table expression (CTE) is used to process the input string three characters at a time to build the dotted target string. The result is used in a query against a sample table.

To see the results from the recursive CTE replace the final `select` statement with the commented `select` immediately above it.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Samples as Table ( SampleId Int Identity, DottedDigits VarChar(20) );
insert into @Samples ( DottedDigits ) values
  ( '1' ), ( '12' ), ( '123' ), ( '1.234' ), ( '12.345' ),
  ( '123.456' ), ( '1.234.567' ), ( '12.345.678' ), ( '123.456.789' );
select * from @Samples;

-- Query the data.
declare @Target as VarChar(15) = '12345678';

with
  Target as (
    -- Get the first group of up to three characters from the tail of the string ...
    select
      Cast( Right( @Target, 3 ) as VarChar(20) ) as TargetString,
      Cast( Left( @Target, case when Len( @Target ) > 3 then Len( @Target ) - 3 else 0 end ) as VarChar(20) ) as Remainder
    union all
    -- ... and concatenate the next group with a dot in between.
    select
      Cast( Right( Remainder, 3 ) + '.' + TargetString as VarChar(20) ),
      Cast( Left( Remainder, case when Len( Remainder ) > 3 then Len( Remainder ) - 3 else 0 end ) as VarChar(20) )
      from Target
      where Remainder != ''
  )
  -- To see the intermediate results replace the final   select   with the line commented out below:
  --select TargetString from Target;
  select SampleId, DottedDigits
    from @Samples
    where DottedDigits = ( select TargetString from Target where Remainder = '' );
```

An alternative approach would be to add a [indexed computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns?view=sql-server-2017) to the table that contains `Replace( CAMPO, '.', '' )`.

Answer (score 0):

If the table containing IDs like `12.345.678` is big (contains many records), I would add a computed field that removes the dots (and if this ID does never contain any alphanumeric characters other than dots and has no significant leading zeros then also cast it in an INT or BIGINT) and persist it and lay an index over it. That way you loose a little time when inserting the record but are querying it with maximum speed and therefore saving processor power.